# Matlab to Opencv converion issue

Tags: c++, matlab, opencv

`A` is a logical matrix of `Mx1`

```
A = (DAL(:,K+1) == i);
```

how can I convert this into C++?

Answer (score 1):

```
Mat1b A = DAL.col(K) == i;
```

---

`DAL` is a matrix (of `double`, since Matlab works with doubles by default) `MxN`:

```
Mat1d DAL = ... // MxN matrix
```

To extract the `K` column (and not `K+1` as in Matlab, because Matlab is 1-based, while C++ is 0 based) you can use the `col` operator:

```
int K = ...
Mat1d columnK = DAL.col(K);
```

Then you can create a logical matrix A (in OpenCV logical matrices are matrix of type `uchar`, with values either `0` or `255`) with:

```
int i = ...
Mat1b A = columnK == i;
```

which will have the same size as `columnK`, i.e. `Mx1`.

So, in practice:

```
int K = ...
int i = ...
Mat1d DAL = ...

Mat1b A = DAL.col(K) == i;
```